User layout which has protected route does not show on the browser. shows a blank page with navigation and side bars
User layout which iterates the pages in the userroutes file only shows the sidebars and navigation bars. shows a blank page and does not show the content of the pages. the urls of the pages are correct only the content of the pages are not shown in the browser. the login function works properly.
1.User Layout.js
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Routes, Route, Navigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import PerfectScrollbar from 'react-perfect-scrollbar';
import 'react-perfect-scrollbar/dist/css/styles.css';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Navbar from '../../../components/Dashboard/Navbar/Navbar';
import Footer from '../../../components/Dashboard/Footer/Footer';
import Sidebar from '../../../components/Dashboard/Sidebar/Sidebar';
import routes from '../Routes/UserRoutes';
import styles from '../../../components/Dashboard/Styles/AdminStyle';
import bgImage from '../../../components/Dashboard/Images/two.jpg';
import logo from '../../../components/Dashboard/Images/one.jpg';

const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);

export default function User({ ...rest }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const mainPanel = useRef(null);
  const location = useLocation();
  const [image, setImage] = useState(bgImage);
  const [color, setColor] = useState('blue');
  const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleDrawerToggle = () => {
    setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mainPanel.current) {
      mainPanel.current.scrollTop = 0;
    }
  }, [location]);

  const getRoutes = (routes) => {
    return routes.map((prop, key) => {
      if (prop.layout === '/user') {
        return (
          <Route
            path={prop.layout + prop.path}
            element={prop.Element}
            key={key}
          />
        );
      }
      return null;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.wrapper}>
      <Sidebar
        routes={routes}
        logoText="User"
        logo={logo}
        image={image}
        handleDrawerToggle={handleDrawerToggle}
        open={mobileOpen}
        color={color}
        {...rest}
      />
      <div className={classes.mainPanel} ref={mainPanel}>
        <Navbar routes={routes} handleDrawerToggle={handleDrawerToggle} {...rest} />
        <PerfectScrollbar>
          <div className={classes.content}>
            <div className={classes.container}>
              <Routes>
                {getRoutes(routes)}
                <Route path="/user" element={<Navigate to="/user/dashboard" replace />} />
              </Routes>
            </div>
          </div>
          <Footer />
        </PerfectScrollbar>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

2.Userroutes.js
import Dashboard from "@material-ui/icons/Dashboard";
import DashboardPage from "../Dashboard.js";
import LendRequests from "../LendRequests.js";
import LoanRequests from "../LoanRequests.js";

const UserRoutes = [
  {
    component: DashboardPage,
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: "Dashboard",
    icon: Dashboard,
    layout: "/user",
  },
  {
    component: LendRequests,
    path: "/lendrequests",
    name: "Lend Requests",
    icon: Dashboard, // You can use a different icon here if needed
    layout: "/user",
  },
  {
    component: LoanRequests,
    path: "/loanrequests",
    name: "Loan Requests",
    icon: Dashboard, // You can use a different icon here if needed
    layout: "/user",
  },
];

export default UserRoutes;

3.app.js
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route, Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import Signin from './containers/Users/SignInUser';
import MainLandingPage from './containers/Users/MainLandingPage';
import SignUp from './containers/Users/Signup';
import PrivateRoute from './components/HOC/PrivateRoute';
import User from './containers/Users/Layout/User';
import LendRequests from './containers/Users/LendRequests';
import Dashboard from './containers/Users/Dashboard';
import LoanRequests from './containers/Users/LoanRequests';
// import Routes from './containers/Users/Routes/';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<MainLandingPage />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Signin />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<SignUp />} />
        <Route path="/user/*" element={<PrivateRoute />}>
          <Route path="*" element={<User />} />
        </Route>
{/* *       <Route element={<User />} path="/user" >
          <Route element={<Dashboard/>} path="/user/dashboard" />
          <Route element={<LoanRequests/>} path="/user/loanrequests" />
          <Route element={<LendRequests/>} path="/user/lendrequests" />
          
           

        </Route>
        */}
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


4.privaterout.js:
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem('isAuthenticated') === 'true'; // Check if user is authenticated

  return isAuthenticated ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
};

export default PrivateRoute;


5.sidebar.js
/*eslint-disable*/
import React from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { NavLink, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
// @material-ui/core components
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";
import Hidden from "@material-ui/core/Hidden";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";
// core components
import NavbarLinks from "../Navbar/NavbarLinks.js";
//*import RTLNavbarLinks from "../Navbars/RTLNavbarLinks.js";

import styles from "../Styles/SidebarStyle.js";

const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);

export default function Sidebar(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  let location = useLocation();
  // verifies if routeName is the one active (in browser input)
  function activeRoute(routeName) {
    return location.pathname === routeName;
  }
  const { color, logo, image, logoText, routes } = props;
  var links = (
    <List className={classes.list}>
      {routes.map((prop, key) => {
        if (prop.display == false){
          return <></>
        }
        var activePro = " ";
        var listItemClasses;
        if (prop.path === "/upgrade-to-pro") {
          activePro = classes.activePro + " ";
          listItemClasses = classNames({
            [" " + classes[color]]: true,
          });
        } else {
          listItemClasses = classNames({
            [" " + classes[color]]: activeRoute(prop.layout + prop.path),
          });
        }
        const whiteFontClasses = classNames({
          [" " + classes.whiteFont]: activeRoute(prop.layout + prop.path),
        });
        return (
          <NavLink
            to={prop.layout + prop.path}
            className={activePro + classes.item}
            activeclassname="active"
            key={key}
          >
            <ListItem button className={classes.itemLink + listItemClasses}>
              {typeof prop.icon === "string" ? (
                <Icon
                  className={classNames(classes.itemIcon, whiteFontClasses, {
                    [classes.itemIconRTL]: props.rtlActive,
                  })}
                >
                  {prop.icon}
                </Icon>
              ) : (
                <prop.icon
                  className={classNames(classes.itemIcon, whiteFontClasses, {
                    [classes.itemIconRTL]: props.rtlActive,
                  })}
                />
              )}
              <ListItemText
                primary={props.rtlActive ? prop.rtlName : prop.name}
                className={classNames(classes.itemText, whiteFontClasses, {
                  [classes.itemTextRTL]: props.rtlActive,
                })}
                disableTypography={true}
              />
            </ListItem>
          </NavLink>
        );
      })}
    </List>
  );
  var brand = (
    <div className={classes.logo}>
      <a
        href="./"
        className={classNames(classes.logoLink, {
          [classes.logoLinkRTL]: props.rtlActive,
        })}
        target="_blank"
      >
        <div className={classes.logoImage}>
          <img src={logo} alt="logo" className={classes.img} />
        </div>
        {logoText}
      </a>
    </div>
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <Hidden mdUp implementation="css">
        <Drawer
          variant="temporary"
          anchor={props.rtlActive ? "left" : "right"}
          open={props.open}
          classes={{
            paper: classNames(classes.drawerPaper, {
              [classes.drawerPaperRTL]: props.rtlActive,
            }),
          }}
          onClose={props.handleDrawerToggle}
          ModalProps={{
            keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
          }}
        >
          {brand}
          <div className={classes.sidebarWrapper}>
            {props.rtlActive ? <RTLNavbarLinks /> : <NavbarLinks />}
            {links}
          </div>
          {image !== undefined ? (
            <div
              className={classes.background}
              style={{ backgroundImage: "url(" + image + ")" }}
            />
          ) : null}
        </Drawer>
      </Hidden>
      <Hidden smDown implementation="css">
        <Drawer
          anchor={props.rtlActive ? "right" : "left"}
          variant="permanent"
          open
          classes={{
            paper: classNames(classes.drawerPaper, {
              [classes.drawerPaperRTL]: props.rtlActive,
            }),
          }}
        >
          {brand}
          <div className={classes.sidebarWrapper}>{links}</div>
          {image !== undefined ? (
            <div
              className={classes.background}
              style={{ backgroundImage: "url(" + image + ")" }}
            />
          ) : null}
        </Drawer>
      </Hidden>
    </div>
  );
}

Sidebar.propTypes = {
  rtlActive: PropTypes.bool,
  handleDrawerToggle: PropTypes.func,
  bgColor: PropTypes.oneOf(["purple", "blue", "green", "orange", "red"]),
  logo: PropTypes.string,
  image: PropTypes.string,
  logoText: PropTypes.string,
  routes: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
  open: PropTypes.bool,
};

I want t use the side bar to switch between protected route pages of user. but the content of the pages are not shown.

The descendent routes will already include "/user" in the path, so don't include it again in the route paths. In other words, path={prop.path} is sufficient for the descendent routes. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Tried several ways to fix this but failed. The problem was the React version. Downgraded from the newer version to the previous version (Last version that allowed to use Switch) and it worked fine.

One thing I can notice in this code is
<Route element={<User />} path="/user" >
  <Route element={<Dashboard/>} path="/user/dashboard" />
  <Route element={<LoanRequests/>} path="/user/loanrequests" />
  <Route element={<LendRequests/>} path="/user/lendrequests" />
</Route

once you wrap the route with a layout route you don't need to repeat the path because now for the dashboard the path will be /user/user/dashboard while when you remove the user part from the path it will be /user/dashboard

I don't think this is the correct way to do protected routes because you are telling it if the path is /user/* load the component user which I assume is the layout for all the user pages.
I think that this:
<Route path="/user/*" element={<PrivateRoute />}>
  <Route path="*" element={<User />} />
</Route>       

need to be
<Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
  <Route element={<User />} path="/user" >
    <Route element={<Dashboard/>} path="/dashboard" />
    <Route element={<LoanRequests/>} path="/loanrequests" />
    <Route element={<LendRequests/>} path="/lendrequests" />
  </Route
</Route>       

I did not have time to check on my solution but if it did not work you can use this tutorial from the web Protected Routes
